# Typecasting objject from Interfaces to derived type c#

Tags: casting

I have following scenario. I have a method which can accept an Interface1 as request and provides Interface2 as response.

```
Interface2 Method(Interface1 request)
{}
```

Now I can have n types of classes implementing these interfaces. For instance

```
Class1Request :Interfac1
Class2Response :Interface2
```

Now what I want is to convert the request to class type here i.e. `Class1Request`.

Please confirm how can I do that dynamically? I want to have a generic method which will typecast request of Interafce1 type to XXXXX class type.

Typecasting object from Interfaces to derived type c#

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. If the function should be dealing with Class1Request types, that's what it should take as input. If you cast to a specific type your method will break when somebody passes in something else that inherits from your interface.

Comment: If you provide a little more detail about what you're trying to accomplish we might be able to give you a better way to do it.

Comment: Here method receives a request object of interface1 type. Now I want to extract the class type from this object which can be done using reflection. After I get the class type, I want to typecast my request into that particular class type. Of course, there can be n number of classes implementing the interface.